# Vanishing Reputation

Tags: bug, reputation

Today I went from $2200$ to $2194$. I checked the reputation tab on my profile and there was nothing there to indicate the loss. Is there any way to see why I lost this reputation?

Comment: did you check the "show removed posts" option at the bottom of the reputation page?

Comment: Yes. $\, \, \,$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A reputation recalc was triggered on your account when you deleted one of your answers. That is why the change showed up *now*.

I however do not know why your reputation display is out of sync with your actual reputation. But just to throw in some possibilities: while deletion and undeletion of your own posts should trigger recalcs, so should not contribute to this. But there are a couple other things that come to mind (that I don't know for sure whether they trigger recalcs)

1. Deletion/undeletion of posts you have downvoted
2. Deletion/undeletion of posts you have proposed edits to

I counted three instances of the second possibility in your history (between December 11, the previous time a rep recalc was triggered and today), which would result in a reduction of 6 points. But this is only a guess, so take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: Is reputation on edit lost when the post gets deleted? I thought it sticks with you... forever and ever!

Comment: @Asaf: yes it is. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145630/155238

Comment: Fascinating. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible that a post you have downvoted in the past got undeleted.

I experienced a similar case recently and I managed to slowly trace it back to that undeletion.